# USB devices gets new ttyU* while still attached raspberry pi 2

Tags: usb, pi-2, temperature, electronics

### Conditions:

I use RP2 for data collection purposes and i am testing its limits. I use it next to diesel engine and its alternator.(I know pi is not for industrial use and this is a prototype.)

There is not too much work load on pi, it is mostly at idle state.
I use industrial grade power supply 5.2V - 5A.
As heat comes from diesel engine i used some fans to cool down pi and i saw cpu temperature is around 50 degree Celcious without any computation.(This is in its range.)
I use usb - rs232 converters for collecting data.(i tried 10 different with high quality chips even used digitus)

### Problem:

When i check ttyUSB*, pi starts from ttyUSB0 but without unpluging and pluging i found my device at ttyUSB16. and there is no ttyUSB0 anymore,

I use a usb detector for measuring voltage and amperage at the end of usb converter, i see that 5V is stable but amperage is getting lower and stucks at some point which leads to problems collecting data.

I double checked pi psu voltage, cable voltage and all, pi is supplied properly for sure. Pi with usb converter attached draws around 400mA at all.

1. Can ambient temperature effect LAN9514(usb controller chip)? makes it stop sending and receving data?
2. Can an alternators electromagnetic interference effect LAN9514(usb controller chip)? The cable is shielded by the way.
3. Is there a way to SCREEN/SHIELD to protect from EMI interference?

   Thanks in advance.